# Не могу разобраться с работой логических вентилей из книги Ч. Петцольда "Код"

Tags: логические-элементы

В книге Петцольд пишет:

> Чтобы привести это начинание в жизнь, рассмотрим пару вентилей ИЛИ-НЕ, соединенных особым образом. Мы помним, что напряжение на
> выходе вентиля ИЛИ-НЕ имеется, только если напряжения нет ни на одном
> из входов.
> Вот как выглядит нужная нам цепь с двумя вентилями ИЛИ-НЕ, двумя переключателями и лампочкой.
> [image: 1]
>
> Провода идут весьма странно: выход левого вентиля ИЛИ-НЕ подключен ко входу правого вентиля ИЛИ-НЕ, а выход правого вентиля ИЛИ-НЕ
> является входом левого вентиля ИЛИ-НЕ. Такое соединение называется
> обратной связью (feedback). Как и в вибраторе, выход цепи является ее
> же входом. Это особенность подавляющего большинства схем,
> рассматриваемых в этой главе.
> Поначалу ток протекает только по цепи от выхода левого вентиля ИЛИ-НЕ. Это происходит из-за того, что оба входа этого вентиля равны
> 0. Замкнем верхний переключатель. Выход левого вентиля ИЛИ-НЕ становится 0, что означает появление 1 на выходе правого вентиля
> ИЛИ-НЕ — лампочка загорается
> [image: 2]

Последний рисунок мне не понятен совсем. Почему при подаче сигнала на нижний вход ИЛИ появляется ещё и сигнал из верхнего входа, ведь ИЛИ состоит из 2 реле, один из которых включен, а второй не может быть включен сигналом первого, т.к. реле не работает в обратную сторону, а сигнал со стороны лампочки не подаётся, т.к. цепь не замкнута

V - это источник питания, соединённый с общим проводом (землёй)

Answer (score 1):

Всё, понял. При замыкании левого ИЛИ его выход становится 0 и сигнал идёт с правого ИЛИ, т.к. его входы становятся 0, а выход соответственно 1